# Is this question fit to be open now?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/162605/why-does-the-stratosphere-have-a-lot-of-ozone-but-not-the-earths-surface) was closed as "Not focused". I have since then edited and simplified. Asking only one aspect now.

Is this now fit to be opened?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know about this; I think it is actually okay... The original question about whether O2 or O3 is more stable was an obvious reason for the closure, but since that's been edited out, I don't see the issue.

I think with some cleaning up of grammar etc. for clarity, this could definitely be reopened.

[One might argue that we should look over problems with grammar etc., but I think the bottom line is that if you make your question look more professional, it will be received better.]

Comment: That's why I voted to reopen it. I don't know why I retracted it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate that writing should be more professional. And also not confusing with multiple questions.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't vote to close but I agree with the action.

Your new "edited and simplified" version contains 4 question marks.

Forgiving sins relating to grammar and punctuation, the query "[o]r any other reason?" alone still does not address the issue.